# URL Shortener Issue

Tags: php, mysql, url

After submitting a URL via the Shortener. It gives the URL with the custom code at the end but rather than redirecting it like I want it to do it give this error code:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL /1njchs was not found on this server.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I am unsure which file it may have the issue in so I have linked all 3.

**Shortener.php:**

```
<?php
class Shortener {
    protected $db;
    
    public function __construct() {
        //Demo Purposes
        $this->db = new mysqli('localhost', 'langers_langers', '^M%Kt3&50PWn','langers_website');
    }

    protected function generateCode($num){
        return base_convert($num, 10, 36);
    }
    
    public function makeCode($url){
        $url = trim($url);
        
        if(!filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
            return '';
        }
    
        $url = $this->db->escape_string($url);
        
        //Check if URL already exists
        $exists = $this->db->query("SELECT code FROM links WHERE url ='{$url}'");
        
        if($exists->num_rows){
            return $exists->fetch_object()->code;
        } else {
        
        //Insert record without a code
        $insert = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO links (url, created) VALUES ('{$url}', NOW())");
        
        //Generate code based on id
        $code = $this->generateCode($this->db->insert_id);
        
        //Update Record
        $this->db->query("UPDATE links SET code = '{$code}' WHERE url = '$url'");
        
        return $code;
        }
    }
    
    public function getUrl($code){
    
        $code = $this->db->escape_string($code);
        
        $code = $this->db->query("SELECT url FROM links WHERE code = '$code'");
        
        
        if($code->num_rows){
            return $code->fetch_object()->url;
        }
        
        return '';
        
    }
}

?>
```

**Redirect.php**

```
<?php
require_once 'classes/Shortener.php';

if(isset($_GET['code'])) {
    $s = new Shortener;
    $code = $_GET['code'];
    
    if($url = $s->getUrl($code)) {
        header("Location: {url}");
        die();
    }
}

header('Location: index.php');
```

**Shorten.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'classes/Shortener.php';

$s = new Shortener;

if(isset($_POST['url'])) {
    $url = $_POST['url'];
        
        if($code = $s->makeCode($url)) {
        $_SESSION['feedback'] = "Generated! Your short URL is: <a href=\"http://r.langers.co/{$code}\">http://r.langers.co/{$code}</a>";
        } else {
          $_SESSION['feedback'] = "There was a problem. Invalid URL, perhaps?";
        }
}

header('Location: index.php');
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with your code and everything to do with your server config. You have to configure your web server to point all URLs at the index.php file for handling.

Comment: Do you have an `.htaccess` set up?  You'll need that to redirect your URLs to the script.

Comment: Are you using `.htaccess`? I'm pretty sure they cover that in the video.

Comment: There is an error in your `Redirect.php` file... the 4th line should be `if(isset($_GET['code'])) {` instead of `if(isset($_GET['code''])) {`

Comment: I have a .htaccess: RewriteEngine On
ReWriteRule ^({a-z0-9]+)$ redirect.php?code=$1

Comment: @user3688665: That should probably be `RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]+)$ redirect.php?code=$1`.  Note the lower case `w` and the `[` in the regex.

Comment: Okay so I changed the Htaccess and edited to Redirect.php however now I get a '500 Internal Server Error' However its only the subdomain thats down not the rest of the site.